# Php Yii2 migration does not work, after execution of migration it does not show option for yes or no

Tags: php, yii2, migration, yii2-advanced-app

When I run `yii migrate` system does not show me an option for yes or no and directly terminate the code.
below is the sample.

```
c:\wamp64\www\app>yii migrate
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.40)

Total 2 new migrations to be applied:
        m130524_201442_init
        m190124_110200_add_verification_token_column_to_user_table

Apply the above migrations? (yes|no) [no]:
c:\wamp64\www\app>
```

Comment: are you on windows ?

Comment: Yes I am windows 10 user.

Comment: You can try adding `--interactive=0` to the command. It would not ask anything. But overall it seems you’ll need something like https://gitforwindows.org/ for console in order for it to work properly.

Comment: Thank you. It really helps, but I dont know why my migrations arent working normal.